# TypeError: this.mesh.geometry.area is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js, leap-motion

I've working lately with JavaScript and Three.js with Leapmotion, and I started using the leap widgets (http://blog.leapmotion.com/leapjs-widgets-new-library-3d-web-design/[here!](http://blog.leapmotion.com/leapjs-widgets-new-library-3d-web-design/)) library to add some cool buttons to my program.

After many hours, I got this type error from one of the libraries. Is it something mine? I just can't figure it out...

```
TypeError: this.mesh.geometry.area is not a function
```

This refers to this code:

```
  this.mass = this.mesh.geometry.area() * this.density;
```

This library doesn't look like its working ok.

Comment: the area function is added to the prototype of PlaneGeometry and CircleGeometry in the leapwidgets js. Make sure you are loading the leapwidgets js after three.js

Comment: yes, I'm doing that but still not working. I'm using the min library, is it possible that the error is there? I'l try.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in this issue: https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs-widgets/issues/4

> `#area` is a custom method added by this project to particular THREE.js geometries.
>
> This error occurs when you try and turn a non-supported geometry in to a button.  Supported geometries are `PlaneGeometry` and `CircleGeometry`.
>
> I have some code sitting around from MozVR which will scale a box to make it look like it is being pushed by a plane.  Here: https://github.com/leapmotion/HIRO/blob/master/js/vrhud.js#L290-L319  Note that scale must be used, because that's the only way to resize an initialized THREE.js geometry.

Edit: This seems to be a fairly common issue. Perhaps in a future release we'll make the error more explicit.